# Auto convert strings and float columns using genfromtxt from numpy/python

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion, genfromtxt

I have several different data files that I need to import using genfromtxt. Each data file has different content. For example, file 1 may have all floats, file 2 may have all strings, and file 3 may have a combination of floats and strings etc. Also the number of columns vary from file to file, and since there are hundreds of files, I don't know which columns are floats and strings in each file. However, all the entries in each column are the same data type.

Is there a way to set up a converter for genfromtxt that will detect the type of data in each column and convert it to the right data type?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use pandas? ``pandas.readcsv`` is much more powerful than ``numpy.genfromtxt``, and will do all of this for you automatically.

Comment: The problem is that I need to be able to convert the output to a numpy array for further processing. I've heard that datafame.as_matrix() returns a object array. So I prefer to use genfromtxt.

Comment: ``dataframe.to_records()`` will give you a record array, which is probably what you want then. Storing mixed types in a numpy array can only be done via a record array or an object array.

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks!

Comment: OK – I added an answer for completeness

Comment: Have you tried `dtype=None`?  It may not as general as the pandas versions, but it does handle this basic dtype inference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to use the Pandas library, `pandas.read_csv` is *much* more generally useful than `np.genfromtxt`, and will automatically handle the kind of type inference mentioned in your question.  The result will be a dataframe, but you can get out a numpy array in one of several ways. e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(filename)

# get a numpy array; this will be an object array if data has mixed/incompatible types
arr = data.values

# get a record array; this is how numpy handles mixed types in a single array
arr = data.to_records()
```

`pd.read_csv` has dozens of options for various forms of text inputs; see more in the [pandas.read_csv documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).